# Problems with GLEventListener

Tags: java, swing, opengl, 3d, jogl

I'm coding a 3D application. I'm trying to get JOGL to work, but nothing shows up. I have a UI class that implements the `GLEventListener` and then implements `display` and `init`. However, from what I can tell from my debugging tool, `display` and `init` are never called, and the scene is never rendered.
Suggestions? I am using a MacBook 2013 with El Capitan OS X, 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB RAM.

```
/**UserInterface class implements tGLEventListener**/

public class UserInterface implements GLEventListener{
    private JTree tree;
    JPopupMenu popupmenu;
    GLRenderer renderer = new GLRenderer();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("NecroTEK 3D Game Graphics Engine");

    public void initUI()
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing UI");
        TreeDemo();

        //JFrame frame = new JFrame("NecroTek 3D Game Modeling Engine");
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.setSize(200, 400);
        popupMenu.setBackground(Color.black);
        popupMenu.setForeground(Color.white);
        popupMenu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));

        /**********MENUBAR - TOP MENU***************/

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menuBar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuBar, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));        

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));

        fileMenu.setToolTipText("Load and Save Projects and Scenes");

        JMenu EditMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        EditMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        EditMenub.setToolTipText("Cut, Copy and Paste");

       display() and init() should be called by the listener but aren't. Right???
             display is supposed to be called every cycle but
            it is never called.

            public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Display");
                renderer.display(arg0);

            }

            public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Dispose");
            }
```

Listener should call this function at least once. But its not.

```
@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Init");
    renderer.init(arg0);
}
@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Reshape");
}
```

I don't understand. It isn't calling the `display` function or `init`.

Comment: Without having looked at your code closely, I'd suggest you cut and paste some example from the JOGL tutorial.  Get that working first.  Then make smaller incremental changes to make the code do what you want.  When you find a problem, stop and debug it thoroughly before continuing.  JOGL is really complicated and tossing code snippets at us probably isn't going to shed much light on the real issue.

Comment: I agree with @markspace, although at one first look I'd say you are missing an animator. You can take an inspiration from this [samples](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle). Take in account they use newt, if you need awt, you need to modify them accordingly.

Comment: I agree with elect and markspace except on one thing, JOGL isn't complicated and the very first example mentionned on Wikipedia (mine) is very rudimentary and works correctly: https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98 Sorry to be harsh but please make some research before asking some help here and before claiming that nothing shows up. Yes you need an animator, nothing is magic and other similar Java APIs are a lot more complicated than JOGL in my humble opinion.

Comment: goussej; couple things. JOGL is just as complicated as regular OpenGL. Second you shouldn't be telling people to start coding OpenGL or JOGL using immediate mode like is used in that example you linked to. Retained mode is standard. And how do you know that I didn't do research I did a ton of research be cause i posted here for help. Because I did. Please don't flame me. Elect: Thanks for your help but I already tried that example.

Comment: You guys keep telling me to use simpler examples. How much simpler canI get than then code to draw a simple triangle on screen? Because that is what I'm doing. Thanks for your help